# How to transform an array of array to a simple array?

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe

I am trying to concatenate columns of different type to create my dataframe but each obtained element of the Dataframe was like this:

`[[259200.0] [259200.0] [259200.0]..., [260099.98] [260099.98] [260099.98]]`

Means if my DF is a matrix so each DF[i,j] is like the above code.

But I want to get a single array of all the sub-arrays like below:

`[259200.0 259200.0 259200.0 ... 260099.98 260099.98 260099.98]`

I will add the pic to clarify more my point :

[image: Here is my final DF]

In fact I am creating this table through the next line :

```
  `features2[i]=pd.DataFrame([[label[i], max[i], mean[i], Cost[1:]])#
   mydataset1=pd.concat([mydataset1,features2[i]], axis=0)`
```

The Cost is already a Table with 140 columns and I want to concatenate it to the other three columns so at the end I will get a DF with 143 columns and N rows

Comment: The problem is that I still could not combine them in the Dataframe

Comment: I strongly suggest you to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer assumes that your data type is a NumPy array as is clear from your title of the question. I am just putting `np.array()` around it to make it a NumPy array because I don't have the DataFrame from which you got this structure.

Then, you can `flatten` your nested array as

```
data = np.array([[259200.0] [259200.0] [259200.0]..., [260099.98] [260099.98] [260099.98]])
new_data = data.flatten() 
# array([259200.  , 259200.  , 259200.  , 260099.98, 260099.98, 260099.98])
```

or using `ravel` as

```
new_data = data.ravel() 
# array([259200.  , 259200.  , 259200.  , 260099.98, 260099.98, 260099.98])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming input as list of list and you want output as simple list

```py
old_data = [[259200.0], [259200.0], [259200.0]]
new_data = []
for item in old_data:
    new_data.append(item[0])
print new_data #[259200.0, 259200.0, 259200.0]
```

Comment: For a true list of lists, a comprehension is more Pythonic.